# Memory leak when loading images with javascript's settimeout

Tags: javascript, html

I have set up a kind of surveillance system, where camera is taking a photo every second and sending this image to server where it overwrites the previous one. On a client side I have a simple javascript with `settimeout` to load this image every second

```
$("img").attr("src", "http://mysite/image.jpg?randomString="+new Date().getTime());
```

But this causes memory leak and eventually the page crashes. 
How to possibly avoid this? Is caching the problem here? Does the browser caches every new image, every second and that's the reason for the memory leaks?

Comment: since you have a different "imagename" each time, the browser of course tries to cache that.

Comment: By crash, do you mean the browser itself actually crashes? There should be absolutely nothing that you can do on a webpage that will cause the browser to crash. If there is, it's a browser bug.

Comment: Can you post more of your javascript code?

Comment: How you know, that this script crash the page!

Comment: Are you sure you're using settimeout? To loop every second you should use setinterval. Make sure its set at 1000 and not 1 (common problem).

Comment: @JordanDoyle actually in many (most) circumstances it's best to call `setTimeout` "recursively" in the callback function than to call `setInterval`.  `setInterval` doesn't play nice when tabs are minimized, and doesn't guarantee a minimum time between callbacks.

Comment: Is `$("img").attr(...)` the *only* code in your `setTimeout` callback?

Comment: @robertklep yes it is.

Comment: Could you just be overloading your browser with requests? If your browser takes more than 1 second to request the image, the number of outstanding requests will pile up; I believe browsers will only open an X amount of connections to the same server. Try waiting for a `load` event on the image before starting a new `setTimeout`.

Comment: ([here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5720354) which implements that, Chrome's memory use stays well stable).

Comment: try using "async" attribute http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Performance/AsyncScripts/Default.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *could* be a caching problem because the browser might cache all these images since they have new image names each time (this shouldn't case a crash though).

In this case, set these caching directives in the header and have a look if it fixes the problem:

```
<!-- disable caching on proxy servers -->
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<!-- set expiration date to "immediately" -->
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<!-- instruct the browser to not cache the webpage -->
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```

On the other hand what might be another problem is your javascript. If the server is not able to handle the http requests in time, you queue up a lot of unresolved http requests in the browser. Try setting the timeout to say 5 seconds (= 5000 ms) in this case.

A third possible solution might be to manipulate the image with plain javascript to eliminate the possibility of jQuery memory leaks.

```
// cache the element once
var img = document.querySelector("img");

// use in setTimeout (Don't create a new Time Object on every call):
img.src = "/image.jpg?randomString="+Date.now();
```

Comment: Filling a browser cache will not cause a crash, or any sort of a memory problem.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, setting these values on an HTML page will affect the caching of that page, but will do nothing about the images loaded by that page.

Comment: @jcsanyi can you prove that? you should let the OP decide whether this helps or not. This is a valid answer in every case. and "as far as i know" is not very convincing.

Comment: @jcsanyi per se the browser caches all elements on the page it might consider useful caching, also images. THese are the official tags to instruct no caching - whether it ignores or abides by them is up to the browser though. (In fact some browser just ignore these meta tags)

Comment: Upvoted to get you to 0. This will help in some cases and since the image is only shown once and there should not be any duplicates the browser shouldnt be caching them anyway.

Comment: The point of a cache is to keep the most recently used items, dropping older items as needed when the cache is full. If caching lots of items caused a crash, then every browser would crash after browsing anywhere for any length of time.

Comment: I'll give it a try @Christoph and see if it helps. Also I could probably set the no-cache headers from the server side too.\

Comment: @jcsanyi the browser itself doesn't crash, only the page, tab becomes unresponsive...

Comment: @fjckls are you using an up-to-date version of jquery? Because old version where known to have memory leaks on ajax calls.

Comment: @Christoph, jquery ver is 1.9.1

Comment: @take a look at my edit and see if this helps. Did anything work out yet?

Comment: @Christoph, I set the headers and now doing some tests - and it seems that it is working... I'll check a bit more and let you know later. Thanks!

Comment: How is changing an image attribute related to memory leaks in AJAX requests?

Comment: @robertklep corrected that in the answer, it's not an ajax request but each src change of course triggers an http request.

Comment: @fjckls Did you locate the problem of the memory leak?

Comment: @Christoph Yes the caching did the trick, I just changed the meta tags, also good points on jquery/javascript optimization. Have my app running all day and no probs. Thanks again!